# Send notifications programmatically using FCM

Tags: java, android, android-studio, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have two android apps, one for admin and one for users. I send the content from the admin, but I send notifications from Onesignal.
I've tried to find a way to send the notifications programmatically from a code inside the admin, the best way is to use the `FCM` (Firebase Cloud Messaging) but I don't know how to use it.
I'm using `android studio` with `JAVA`.

I've tried the `FCM` but I still don't know how to send a notification.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Cloud Messaging supports sending messages from either the Firebase console (its web-based admin interface) or through its API **from trusted environments**. This is best illustrated by this diagram from the documentation on the [Firebase Cloud Messaging arcitecture](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/fcm-architecture):

[image]

So there is no way to send messages directly from one Android device to another through (just) FCM. You will need some sort of trusted environment, such as your development machine, a server that you control, or Cloud Functions/Cloud Run, to send messages from.

For an example of this, you can have a look at the Cloud Functions sample use-case of [notifying the user when something interesting happens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#notify_users_when_something_interesting_happens) or at my classic blog post [Sending notifications between Android devices with Firebase Database and Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.blog/posts/2016/08/sending-notifications-between-android/).